# My server seems to be sharing publically but I can't access anything

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008

I have a server running windows server 2008 R2.

I want to share a folder, so I can access it via `\\ip`

In the network settings > advanced sharing settings, I have enabled Password Protected Sharing.

However when I type `\\ip` I see the shared folders without being prompted for a username/password.

When I try to access the folder I shared, I get an access denied with no prompt to enter a username/password.

Any idea how to resolve this so I can access the shared files and not have anything publically showing?

Comment: What client are you using to access the shared folder? (Windows 7/8/XP/Mac?)

Answer (score 0):

**To Hide Shared Folder:**
To "hide" shared folder you can use myfolder$

Any share folder with $ ending will be hidden when you simply browse for shared folder \ip

So the only way to access it is to know the exact path \ip\myfolder$

**Access denied issue**

1. Create the folder you wanted to share
2. Right click on the folder and choose "Properties"
3. Under Sharing Tab - Advanced Sharing
4. Under Advanced Sharing -> Sharing Name myfolder$
5. Under Permission -> Add your username that need to have access (local username on the server, or domain username) - and ensure it has the correct permission (Full Control / Change / Read)
6. Done

If you are using local username, then when you attempted to go to \ip it may just work showing all other shared folders, and when going into \ip\myfolder$ it should prompt you for username / password - or may just reject you flat. 
If it rejects you flat without asking for username/password, try mapping the drive, and ensure you use the correct username/password combination, and if needed, prefix the username with the server name (SERVER\local-user).

Hope this helps.